# Running shell scripts as root in php?

Tags: php

I am trying to write a php script to add users to an LDAP. To this end I have a shell script, aptly titled "addldapuser.sh", that will take in user/screenname/password combinations and add them to the LDAP. This script works properly. We would like users to be able to enter their information on a web form, which will then invoke said script and add the user to the LDAP properly. The addldapuser script currently needs to be run as root, and while I am aware of the security concerns, they can be dealt with later. I have tried everything I can think of or find, gave everything every permission I could think of, gave everything I could root, mucked around with Apache for awhile, and now I am out of ideas.

```
$scrName = $_POST['screenname'];
$usrName = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $out =  nl2br(shell_exec("sudo /EasyLDAP/old_scripts/addldapuser.sh " . $usrName . " " . $scrName . " " . $pass));

}
```

Once again, I know this is just a terrible, terrible idea that is guaranteed to end in hackers destroying us all forever, but my boss wants me to at least make it function this way.

I do know that we should at least sanitize the input, and that will be taken care of in due time.

Comment: On many systems, `sudo` cannot be run without a real tty shell.  Look for `requiretty` in your sudoers file.  And if you are running something like SELinux or AppArmor, they're likely to forbid this as well.

Comment: Also, be sure to call `escapeshellcmd()` on this before executing it or `escapeshellarg()` on the name inputs.

Comment: As Michael pointed out, this script is terrifying.  You'll be hacked within days.  Why not use the PHP functions for LDAP?  Why would an LDAP script require sudo privs anyway?

Comment: This is a horrible, **horrible** idea.  What if someone logs in with a username of `;sudo rm -Rf /#`?  Tell your boss that if he wants it to function this way, then s/he alone is responsible for the inevitable hacking of the company's webservers.

Comment: Dealing with the security concerns later is asking for a hackish solution.  Deal with them now, that way your program will be less likely to fail

Comment: This gaping security hole "will be taken care of in due time"?  No.  No it won't.  You can't sanitize input to a system that's been destroyed.  The **only** reasonable answer to what you're trying to ask is "Don't do it.  Ever."

Comment: 0_0  Who up-voted this question?!

Comment: Ok...if I see any more indignant yelling and hyperbole noise aimed at the OP then I'll just purge the comments, I think he/she "gets it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell, you can easily get a shell with root. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);

$strCmd = "/EasyLDAP/old_scripts/addldapuser.sh " . $usrName . " " . $scrName . " " . $pass;
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd($strCmd);

echo $return1;// return from your script
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creation of a daemon, which will be running as a root and will communicate with a script running at a user level.

You can do very simple python rpc server (e.g. XML-RPC which is built-in) and a client as a glue, run one of them as a server and root and the other one make into a client script.

The php code would then execute the python script with the required parameters, which then can communicate with the python server script.

As a benefit, you get potential security if you do the server part well. I chose python as a language which has most of the functionality built-in and is very simple to use.

Examples:

server - http://docs.python.org/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html#simplexmlrpcserver-example

client - http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html#example-of-client-usage

Alternatively, if you insist on using php, you can run the server process as a [php daemon](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/) and connect to it via some similar RPC means.